# Remove Duplicate Entry in Sql Table with Select Query

Tags: sql, duplicates

Hello I am trying to remove duplicate "Name" entries from the following table.
I have tried the count (Name) but still cant seem to remove the duplicate.

How can i do this please?

[image]

Comment: Can you post the code and output behind your image please, it's being blocked by my web provider

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL Server`, etc..) that you are using.

Comment: Are you trying to do this in code?  Or with a SQL statement?  As other commenters have said you should probably include what you have tried and tag appropriately to get attention from the right folks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `subquery` :

```
select t.*
from table t
where id1 = (select top 1 id1
             from table t1 
             where t1.name  = t.name
             order by t1.id2
            );
```

Comment: Awesome thanks for this! Just what i needed but couldn't get my head round it.